# AngularJS, filter only if a variable is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat with many filters.

(1) From an input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
```

(2) Another one from a list of buttons:

```
<ul id="element_filter" class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill uk-margin-remove">
    <li ng-class="statusFilter == '' ? 'uk-active' : ''"><a ng-click="statusFilter = ''">Tutti</a></li>
    <li ng-class="statusFilter == '1' ? 'uk-active' : ''"><a ng-click="statusFilter = '1'">Nuovo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Connected to a custom filter named `filtraStato`

(3) Than I have a checkbox:

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_demo_inline" id="checkbox_mostra_zone" ng-model="openFiltraZone" data-md-icheck />
    <label for="checkbox_mostra_zone" class="inline-label">Filtra Zone</label>
</div>
```

This is also connected to a custom filter `filtraZona`

I then have an ng-repeat where the filter `filtraZona` should be active only if the checkbox `openFiltraZone` is checked.

I don't know what to put on the repeater expression in order to apply the filter only if `openFiltraZone` is checked

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clienti | filter:search | filtraStato:statusFilter | filtraZona:zonaFilter">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only way is to write custom filter function for that, like this:

In controller/directive:

```
var _filter = $filter('filtraZona');
$scope.filterFnc = function(elem) {
  if(!$scope.openFiltraZone) return true; //leave on list when openFiltraZone is not checked
  return _filter([elem], $scope.zonaFilter).length > 0; //this will get filtraZona filter and apply it to one element array (created with [elem] expression) with $scope.zonaFilter parameter. Whole expression will return true only if filtraZona will not filter out elem.
}
```

In view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clienti | filter:search | filtraStato:statusFilter | filter:filterFnc">
```

I believe that this is the only way if you do not want to change `filtraZona` filter. Please notice, that this is not the most cpu-efficient way.

If you can change `filtraZona` implementation, you can add simple pre-check to it's code:

```
angular.filter('filtraZona', function() {
  return function(arr, param1, checkboxChecked) {
    var arr2 = [];
    angular.forEach(arr, function(elem) {
      if(!checkboxChecked) arr2.push(elem);
      //rest of filtraZona logic goes here
    });
    return arr2;
  };
});
```

And use it this way (notice second parameter to `filtraZona`):

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clienti | filter:search | filtraStato:statusFilter | filtraZona:zonaFilter:openFiltraZone">
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply have it like

```
item in items | filter: box ? search: ''"
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SwrYVGROHjNJ39LgiN5U?p=preview)

Comment: This works ok but not completely, I have more filters, so I edited the original question, could you check it out again? Tks

Comment: @pankaj This really helped me. See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645585/angularjs-apply-custom-filter-only-when-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but this works for me with angular 1.x:

```
| filter:{other filters, active: (active ? true : "")}
```