# angularjs apply custom filter only when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-filter

this is my controller :

```
app.controller('listdata', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.users = [{
    "name": "pravin",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "456",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7411173737"
},
{
    "name": "pratik",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "8558855858"
},
{
    "name": "priyanka",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "5454573737"
},
{
    "name": "prerana",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7454543737"
}];

  $scope.filter111 = function (user) {
            return (user.queue.find(({number}) => number === '111'));
        }
});
```

and this is my view :

```
<label class="switch">
  <input ng-true-value='111' ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111">111
</label>

<div class="row" ng-controller="listdata">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users|filter:queue111">
       <p> {{user.name}} {{user.phone}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I start the app all the four users from the users data array are displayed. When I click on the filter checkbox, it displays the users who have a queue with a number 111. but it also displays the user pravin as it contains a phone number 7411173737 which contains 111. I want this filter to only display records whose queue number matches with 111 and not with any other fields like the phone number here. So the filter should only display records where the queue number is 111.

> What I have done till now :

I have come up with a custom function `$scope.filter111` as shown in the code above which returns only those users who have a queue number as 111. I want to use this function as a filter when the checkbox is checked. If I directly do ng-repeat="user in users|filter:filter111" it only displays records with queue number 111(i.e only 3 records) when the app starts(all the four records should be displayed when app starts). So I want this function to be fired only when I check the checkbox and apply it as a filter. 
I was think of something like this :

```
<input ng-true-value="'filter111'" ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111">111
```

but it's not working this way.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: `ng-repeat="user in users|filter:{name:queue111"}`

Comment: will this execute the filter111 function?

Comment: Do not use custom filter, i suggest use exact match,   `ng-repeat="user in users|filter:{name:queue111"}:true`

Comment: not working for me. as i want to display only the objects where the queue number is 111

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/kw8rysc5/4/

Comment: Pravin your input checkbox in not inside controller, see the html

Comment: your fiddle works perfectly. but no idea why it's not working when I implemented the same in my code

Comment: I tried to put it inside the controller and still not working

Comment: please see my answer. I got it to work by using a ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it like this by using the ternary operator in the filter:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('listdata', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.users = [{
    "name": "pravin",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "456",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7411173737"
},
{
    "name": "pratik",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    },
    {
        "number": "112",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "8558855858"
},
{
    "name": "priyanka",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "5454573737"
},
{
    "name": "prerana",
    "queue": [{
        "number": "111",
        "status": "Unavailable"
    }],
    "phone": "7454543737"
}];
   $scope.filter111 = function (user) {
            return (user.queue.find(({number}) => number === '111'));
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="queue111">111
</label>


<div class="row" ng-controller="listdata">

  <div ng-repeat="user in users|filter: queue111? filter111: ''">
    <p> {{user.name}} {{user.phone}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```